# sql query logic

Tags: sql, oracle, logic, lag, analytical

I have following data set

> ```
>        a      b      c
>       `1`     2      3
>        3      6      9  
>        9      2      11
> ```

As you can see column a's first value is fixed (i.e. 1), but from second row it picks up the value of column c of previous record.

Column b's values are random and column c's value is calculated as c = a + b

I need to write a sql query which will select this data in above format. I tried writing using lag function but couldn't achieve.

Please help.

**Edit :**
 Column `b` exists in table only, `a and c` needs to calculated based on the values of `b`.

Hanumant

Comment: You want to select data in above format or insert it in that format. if it is already inserted simply select statement will give u the result

Comment: sorry, my mistake, the result should be selected as above. there is only b column existing a and c needs to calculated.

Comment: I now see your edit and that raises the question in what order do you want your rows to be processed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SQL> select a
  2       , b
  3       , c
  4    from dual
  5   model
  6         dimension by (0 i)
  7         measures (0 a, 0 b, 0 c)
  8         rules iterate (5)
  9         ( a[iteration_number] = nvl(c[iteration_number-1],1)
 10         , b[iteration_number] = ceil(dbms_random.value(0,10))
 11         , c[iteration_number] = a[iteration_number] + b[iteration_number]
 12         )
 13   order by i
 14  /

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          4          5
         5          8         13
        13          8         21
        21          2         23
        23         10         33

5 rows selected.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the relation between the rows ,how can we calculate the sum of the previous row `a and b` column  to current row `a column` .I have created two more `column id and parent` in the table to find the relation between the two rows.

`parent` is the column which tell us about the `previous row` ,and `id` is the `primary key` of the row .

```
create table test1 (a number ,b number ,c number ,id number ,parent number);

Insert into TEST1 (A, B, C, ID) Values (1, 2, 3, 1);
Insert into TEST1 (B, PARENT, ID) Values (6, 1, 2);
Insert into TEST1 (B, PARENT, ID) Values (4, 2, 3);

  WITH recursive (a, b, c,rn) AS
    (SELECT a,b,c,id rn
       FROM test1 
      WHERE parent IS NULL
    UNION ALL
     SELECT  (rec.a+ rec.b) a
             ,t1.b b
             ,(rec.a+ rec.b+t1.b) c
             ,t1.id rn
      FROM recursive rec,test1 t1
      WHERE t1.parent = rec.rn
    )
     SELECT a,b,c
      FROM recursive;
```

[image: output]

1. The `WITH keyword` defines the name `recursive` for the subquery that is to follow

   WITH recursive (a, b, c,rn) AS
2. Next comes the first part of the named subquery

   `SELECT a,b,c,id rn
       FROM test1 
      WHERE parent IS NULL`

The named subquery is a `UNION ALL` of two queries. This, the first query, defines the starting point for the recursion. As in my CONNECT BY query, I want to know what is the start with record.

Next up is the part that was most confusing :

```
SELECT  (rec.a+ rec.b) a
             ,t1.b b
             ,(rec.a+ rec.b+t1.b) c
             ,t1.id rn
  FROM recursive rec,test1 t1
  WHERE t1.parent = rec.rn
```

This is how it works :

- WITH query: 1. The parent query executes:

  `SELECT a,b,c
        FROM recursive;`

  - This triggers execution of the named subquery. 2 The first query in the subquery's  union executes, giving us a seed row with which to begin the recursion:

  `SELECT a,b,c,id rn
      FROM test1 
     WHERE parent IS NULL`

The seed row in this case will be for id =1 having parent is null. Let's refer to the seed row from here on out as the "new results", new in the sense that we haven't finished processing them yet.

- The second query in the subquery's union executes:

  `SELECT  (rec.a+ rec.b) a
               ,t1.b b
               ,(rec.a+ rec.b+t1.b) c
               ,t1.id rn
    FROM recursive rec,test1 t1
    WHERE t1.parent = rec.rn`